# Will Nina be a long-haired cat?

Tags: cats, strays

Our Nina is a street cat rescue. She was very hungry and frightened of the dogs around. Her vet said she is 9 or 10 weeks old and I just wonder will she be this much fluffy when she's a grown up. Will she be a long haired cat?

[image: Nina]
[image: Nina]
[image: Nina]

Comment: At least somewhat fluffy - true shorthair kittens are less fluffy, apart from that, check out the linked question. Congratulations to the new family member, good luck and welcome to Pets SE!

Comment: She looks a lot like one of my cats did as a kitten, so there's a good chance. The linked question has a lot of helpful information for you, as well. Feel free to hop into chat, too, if you'd like to see how mine turned out.

Comment: I am over 90% sure that Nina will be long-haired cat.